# Date.TryParse incorrect results

Tags: .net, vb.net

When using `Date.TryParse`, why would a string input of "2015-03-02-01" succeed during conversion from `string` to `Date`, with result of "3/1/2015 8:00:00 PM"?  Using VS2013 targeting .NET 4.0.

I would expect `Date.TryParse` to return false in this case.

If it did succeed, I would expect it to return with either

1. "3/**2**/2015" ignoring the final "-01"
2. "3/1/2015 **11**:00:00 PM"
   if it treated the final "-01" as minus one hour from "2015-03-02"
3. "3/1/2015 **7**:00:00 PM" if it treated the final "-01" as minus one
   hour and then applied the current US Eastern Daylight Time UTC
   offset of -4 as well.

Any idea of what is going on here internally that would cause it to return "3/1/2015 **8**:00:00 PM"?

Here is a test case:

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub TestDateTryParse()
    Dim s As String = "2015-03-02-01"
    Dim d As Date
    If Date.TryParse(s, d) Then
        Assert.Fail("Date parsed when should have failed. Input: ""{0}"", Output: ""{1}""", s, d)
    End If
End Sub
```

Test Result Message:    Assert.Fail failed. Date parsed when should have failed. Input: "2015-03-02-01", Output: "3/1/2015 8:00:00 PM"

Comment: The conversion is dependent on the current thread culture, with en-US it will output 3/2/2015 1:00:00 AM, https://dotnetfiddle.net/LFC8kQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is interpreted as `2015-03-02` at timezone `-01`.

The documentation for [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) has this to say:

> If `s` contains no time zone information, *result* contains a `DateTime` value whose `Kind` property is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` when the method returns. If the string to be parsed contains time zone information, result contains a `DateTime` value whose `Kind` property is `DateTimeKind.Local` when the method returns.

So, for a very normal date string like `2015-03-02`, when you parse it using `DateTime.TryParse()`, you will see that the date's `Kind` property will be `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` as documented.

But if you check the `Kind` property in your funny case, you will see that it will give you `DateTimeKind.Local`, indicating that the parsing operation detected timezone information.

So what happens in this case is that ***your*** local timezone must be `-05`. (**EDIT**: or more precisely, ***was*** `-05` on `2015-03-02`. Because of daylight savings time, your current timezone may be different, but the timezone that matters is the one that was in effect on `2015-03-02`)  So when it parses `2015-03-02-01`, here is what it does:

- Interpret `2015-03-02-01` as `2015-03-02 12:00:00 AM` at timezone `-01`
- Convert `2015-03-02 12:00:00 AM` at timezone `-01` to the local timezone `-05`: `2015-03-01 08:00:00 PM`

Comment: Thank you for the info, that is very interesting.  My local timezone is -04 which is EDT.  Running `(Date.UtcNow - Date.Now).ToString()` returns `"04:00"`.  So wouldn't that mean that it should return 9pm, since 3/2/2015 12am at -01 local timezone converted to -04 timezone would be -03 hrs which would be 3/1/2015 9pm?

Comment: That's because daylight savings is not active in the beginning of march.  So for March 2nd, 2015, your timezone really is `-05`.  If you change the string to be parsed to `2015-07-02-01` (July), you'll see that the time offset will be different to reflect daylight savings time.

Answer (score 3):

The "-01" at the end of your string is being interpreted as a time zone offset from UTC (more commonly known as GMT).